# How to disable FTP port (Debian)?

Tags: nginx, ftp, debian, port

I am newbie in Debian. I have open FTP port (21) on Debian 6 (http server of the system is Nginx). How I can stop or disable the port via service or somehow yet? The command `/etc/init.d/proftpd stop` is not working, it shows in console `bash: /etc/init.d/proftpd: No such file or directory` because `proftpd` is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Inputing this command `netstat -tnlp`, you can find which process is running on port 21.

Then you can some work by youself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to lazy to stop the service from running you can write an iptables rule

```
sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port {PORT-NUMBER-HERE} -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking if your port is listening

```
sudo ss -tulnp | grep LISTEN
Netid State  Recv-Q  Send-Q    Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port Process 
tcp   LISTEN 0      5           127.0.0.1:29754      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("vpnagentd",pid=960,fd=4))       
tcp   LISTEN 0      128           0.0.0.0:17500      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("dropbox",pid=3129583,fd=48))    
tcp   LISTEN 0      50            0.0.0.0:445        0.0.0.0:*    users:(("smbd",pid=923696,fd=48))        
tcp   LISTEN 0      128         127.0.0.1:17600      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("dropbox",pid=3129583,fd=67))    
tcp   LISTEN 0      128         127.0.0.1:17603      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("dropbox",pid=3129583,fd=75))    
tcp   LISTEN 0      50            0.0.0.0:139        0.0.0.0:*    users:(("smbd",pid=923696,fd=49))        
tcp   LISTEN 0      32            0.0.0.0:53         0.0.0.0:*    users:(("dnsmasq",pid=1276,fd=7))        
tcp   LISTEN 0      32            0.0.0.0:21         0.0.0.0:*    users:(("vsftpd",pid=1230,fd=3))         
tcp   LISTEN 0      128           0.0.0.0:22         0.0.0.0:*    users:(("sshd",pid=43857,fd=3))          
tcp   LISTEN 0      128         127.0.0.1:631        0.0.0.0:*    users:(("cupsd",pid=3138801,fd=7))       
tcp   LISTEN 0      128              [::]:17500         [::]:*    users:(("dropbox",pid=3129583,fd=47))    
tcp   LISTEN 0      2                   *:3389             *:*    users:(("xrdp",pid=1306,fd=11))          
tcp   LISTEN 0      50               [::]:445           [::]:*    users:(("smbd",pid=923696,fd=46))        
tcp   LISTEN 0      50               [::]:139           [::]:*    users:(("smbd",pid=923696,fd=47))        
tcp   LISTEN 0      32               [::]:53            [::]:*    users:(("dnsmasq",pid=1276,fd=9))        
tcp   LISTEN 0      128              [::]:22            [::]:*    users:(("sshd",pid=43857,fd=4))          
tcp   LISTEN 0      2               [::1]:3350          [::]:*    users:(("xrdp-sesman",pid=1295,fd=7))    
tcp   LISTEN 0      128             [::1]:631           [::]:*    users:(("cupsd",pid=3138801,fd=6))
```

So, you see in port 21 you have service vsftpd listening.

You can check the status:

```
sudo service vsftpd status
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-07-19 09:42:45 EDT; 2 months 15 days ago
   Main PID: 1230 (vsftpd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38363)
     Memory: 972.0K
        CPU: 7ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
             └─1230 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Now, you can block the port with the firewall (for example you can use ufw), or stop the service

```
$ sudo service vsftpd stop
$ sudo service vsftpd status
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2022-10-03 10:55:50 EDT; 9s ago
    Process: 1230 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=killed, signal=TERM)
   Main PID: 1230 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
        CPU: 7ms

Oct 03 10:55:50 Tuxy systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 03 10:55:50 Tuxy systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Succeeded.
Oct 03 10:55:50 Tuxy systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd FTP server.
```

So, in summary. Install ufw. Unblock only ports you are going to use (ssh, etc). Start only the services you are going to use. (sudo service *** start/stop)
good luck